# How do I code the c program that calculates the Euclidean distance in matrix form?

Tags: c

After taking the X and Y coordinates of 5 points in the Cartesian coordinate system (P0, P1, P2, P3, P4) from the user and placing them in a single array (not two arrays, certainly in a single array) I want to code a program that puts it in a 2-dimensional Euclidean distance array as follows.

```
Array of coordinates (vector with 10 elements) 
X0 Y0 X1 Y1 X2 Y2 X3 Y3 X4 Y4


 Euclidean distance array (matrix in 5x5 form) 
    P1 -> P0 Distance
    P2 -> P0 Distance   P2 -> P1 Distance 
    P3 -> P0 Distance   P3 -> P1 Distance  P3 -> P2 Distance
    P4 -> P0 Distance   P4 -> P1 Distance  P4 -> P2 Distance  P4 -> P3 Distance
```

For numbers 1 to 10, I just get this printout.

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

My codes

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <math.h>



int main() {
        int k[5][2],s[5][2];
        int i=0,j=0,p=0,z=0,x1,x2,y1,y2;
        for(i=0;i<5;i++){
        for(j=0;j<2;j++){
                printf("enter coordinates");
                scanf("%d",&k[i][j]);
            }
        }
        for(i=0;i<5;i++){
            for(j=0;j<2;j++){
                printf("%d\t",k[i][j]);
        }
        }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes, the similarity is pretty much, but I still have no idea how to print it in the last way I said, so 5 X 5 matrix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To calculate the distances:

```
int getDistance (int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2)
{
    double distance = pow(x2 - x1, 2) + pow(y2 - y1, 2);
    distance = sqrt(distance);

    return (int)distance;
}
```

Use a nested loop to populate a distances array:

```
int distances [5][5];

for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) //rows
{
    for (j = 0; j < 5; j++) //cols
    {
        distances[i][j] = getDistance(k[i][0], k[i][1], k[j][0], k[j][1]);
    }
}
```

and another nested loop to print the distances array:

```
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) //rows
{
    for (j = 0; j < 5; j++) //cols
    {
        printf("%d ", distances[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Complete code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <math.h>

int getDistance (int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2)
{
    double distance = pow(x2 - x1, 2) + pow(y2 - y1, 2);
    distance = sqrt(distance);

    return (int)distance;
}

int main() {

    int k[5][2],s[5][2];
    int i=0,j=0,p=0,z=0,x1,x2,y1,y2;

    for(i=0;i<5;i++){
        for(j=0;j<2;j++){
            printf("enter coordinates");
            scanf("%d",&k[i][j]);
        }
    }

    //populate array
    int distances [5][5];

    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) //rows
    {
        for (j = 0; j < 5; j++) //cols
        {
            distances[i][j] = getDistance(k[i][0], k[i][1], k[j][0], k[j][1]);
        }
    }

    //print distances
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) //rows
    {
        for (j = 0; j < 5; j++) //cols
        {
            printf("%d ", distances[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    for(i=0;i<5;i++){
        for(j=0;j<2;j++){
            printf("%d\t",k[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

result:

```
0 2 5 8 11
2 0 2 5 8
5 2 0 2 5
8 5 2 0 2
11 8 5 2 0
```

Comment: `pow(x2 - x1, 2)` risks integer overflow.  `pow(0.0 + x2 - x1, 2)` does not.  Of course, the final `return (int)distance;` overflows either way.